# puppetd --test err: Could not request certificate: Connection refused - connect(2) Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-12.10, puppet

I m new to puppet and i m trying to have connection to my puppet server, when i ping to my puppetmaster it runs well but when i run puppetd --test t shows me following error.

puppetd --test
info: Creating a new SSL key for neeraj-aspire-5738
err: Could not request certificate: Connection refused - connect(2)
Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled

I have install puppetmaster as well as puppet(as client) on to my ubuntu 12.10 distro

i don't know much commands in puppet, So please let me know any command output that u require

Answer (score 1):

The agent has no signed certificate.

At first invoking this command, the agent sends a certificate request to puppetmaster. If the command is run with a parameter `--waitforcert 20` then the agent will wait until his certificate request is signed by the puppetmaster and 20 second there is a period between attempts.

On server where puppetmaster is running, you have to sign his request, e.g. with command:

```
puppet cert --all sign
```

Also ensure that server hostname is specified in "/etc/puppet/puppet.conf"

```
[main]
    server = puppet.example.com
```

Newer version abandoned this command in favor `puppet agent --test`.

For testing purpose you can enable autosign, but is generally unsafe.

```
[main]
    autosign = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used puppet myself, but found this on a quick search:

> fix was
>   to put a 'hashed' link in the openssl certs directory to the CA
>   certificate on the agent machine. So you if you haven't already
>   copied your ca.pem or ca_crt.pem file to the agent host, that is
>   your first step.
>
> openssl version -d
>
> [will give you give you base openssl dir]
>
> openssl x509 -hash -noout -in /etc/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem
>
> [will give you CA cert hash...something like 520f3686]
>
> go into the openssl dir you received from above and create a 'hashed' link in the certs directory to your CA cert file.
>
> ls -al /etc/pki/tls/certs/520f3686.0
>
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jun 22 02:21 /etc/pki/tls/certs/520f3686.0 -
>
> /etc/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crt.pem
>
> Note that a ".0" is added the end of your hash when creating the link.

from: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/puppet-users/-knxubNs6sY

Answer (score -1):

Try to run following command

```
puppet master --no-daemonize --verbose
```

Try again to generate certificate from client